How i can migrate AWS sagemaker notebook instance from Amazon Linux version 1 to 2 taking in account that i can't access the VMs anymore?
I'm in a new project that has some notebook instances created in sagemaker that are from the Amazon Linux 1 platform that had its support recently ended and at the moment the notebooks don't even turn on anymore.
I wanted to know if there is any way to access the files from these machines to be able to move them to the new instances that are created.
Obs: It is not possible to edit the platform of the created instances, this option is disabled.

You should post your question on superuser.com or serverfault.com instead of stackoverflow as its not about programming (or maybe the aws forums). It seems AL1 has been deprecated for a while and reached end of life in March this year so its not looking good if they are in the stopped state, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-al2.html#nbi-al2-deprecation

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As one of the comments mentions (docs), AL1 has been on a path to deprecation, and as of March 31, 2024, you won't be able to run a notebook on AL1 if the notebook was stopped.
Please raise a ticket through enterprise support if that's an option, to see if they can back up the EBS volume and provide a copy. Editing the platform is not an option.

You are right. We opened a ticket and they allowed us to access the instances for another 1 month and then we were able to make backups.
